# Select onchange to Controller's Action in .net-core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a list of objects classified by type, so I have a "type" select on my view

```
<form asp-action="Index" asp-route-type=" ? selectedTypeId ? ">
    <select asp-items="ViewBag.Types" onchange="this.form.submit()"></select>
</form>
```

my controller's action is

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromQuery(Name = "type")] int type) {
   // filter the object list by type 
}
```

How do I correctly reload the view by using the select?

I saw Ajax solution are proposed and it would be a great solution, however my problem is that when I change the product type, not only the product list changes, but also the product characteristics (columns), also the create button should create only that type of products, so, it changes all the view behavior. I'll rather reload all the view than a part of it.

Answer (score 14):

> How do I correcly reload the view by using the select?

It seems that you want to filter data based on the DropDownList selected value, in my opinion, I prefer to use Partial View to display the filtered data and use JQuery Ajax to update the content. Please refer the following sample:

Create a ProductViewModel view model:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

Controller method:

```
    //ProductIndex Page
    public IActionResult ProductIndex()
    {
        //get all the initial data from the repository
        var productlist = _repo.GetProductViewModels();

        //set select items for the DropDownList
        ViewBag.Types = _repo.GetProductViewModels().Select(c=>c.ProductType).Distinct().ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c, Value = c }).ToList();
        return View(productlist);
    }

    //based on the type filter data and return partial view.
    public IActionResult ShowProduct(string type)
    {
        var productlist = _repo.GetProductViewModels().ToList();

        //based on the type to filter data.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(type) && type != "all")
        {
            productlist = productlist.Where(c => c.ProductType == type).ToList();
        }

        //required using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
        ViewBag.Types = _repo.GetProductViewModels().Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.ProductType, Value = c.ProductType }).Distinct().ToList();
        return PartialView("_ShowProductPartialView", productlist );
    }
```

Create a `_ShowProductPartialView.cshtml` partial view to display the product list:

```
@model IEnumerable<netcore5.Models.ProductViewModel>
 
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductType)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductType)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Code in the ProductIndex Page:

```
@model IEnumerable<netcore5.Models.ProductViewModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ProductIndex";
}

<h1>ProductIndex</h1>
 
<form asp-action="ProductIndex">
    <select id="ddltype" name="type" asp-items="ViewBag.Types" >
        <option value="all">All Type</option>
    </select>
    <div id="productcontainer"> 
        <partial name="_ShowProductPartialView.cshtml" model="@Model" />
    </div> 
</form>


@section Scripts{ 
<script>  
    $(function () {
        $("#ddltype").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "/Home/ShowProduct?type=" + $(this).val(),  //remember change the controller to your owns.  
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#productcontainer").html("");
                    $("#productcontainer").html(data);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Then, the result like this:

[image]

[Note] By using the above method, the main page will not update, just refresh the partial view.

If you want to use the `<select>` element `onchange` event, you could add a `Submit` button in the Form, and in the `onchange` event, click the `Submit` button, it will submit the form. Then, you can filter data based on the type.

Change the above code as below: In the ProductIndex.cshtml page, remove the JQuery script and add a Submit button, add name attribute for the `select` element, then, in the select `onchange` event, click the Submit button:

```
@model IEnumerable<netcore5.Models.ProductViewModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ProductIndex";
}

<h1>ProductIndex</h1>
 
<form asp-action="ProductIndex">
    <select id="ddltype" name="type" asp-items="ViewBag.Types" onchange="document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click();" >
        <option value="all">All Type</option>
    </select>
    <div id="productcontainer"> 
        <partial name="_ShowProductPartialView.cshtml" model="@Model" />
    </div>

    <input id="btnSubmit" hidden type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Code in the Controller:

```
    public IActionResult ProductIndex(string type)
    {
        //get all the initial data from the repository
        var productlist = _repo.GetProductViewModels();

        //based on the type to filter data.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(type) && type != "all")
        {
            productlist = productlist.Where(c => c.ProductType == type).ToList();
        }

        //set select items for the DropDownList
        ViewBag.Types = _repo.GetProductViewModels().Select(c=>c.ProductType).Distinct().ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c, Value = c }).ToList();
        return View(productlist);
    }
```

The result like this:

[image]

As we can see that, the Main page will refresh. So, I prefer to use JQuery Ajax to load the partial view.

Comment: my problem is that when I change the product type, not only the product list changes, but also the product characteristics (columns), also the create button should create only that type of products, so, it changes all the view behavior. I'll rather reload all the view than a part of it.

Comment: Hi @Serge, "When I change the product type, not only the product list changes, but also the product characteristics (columns), " From the original description, we just see that you want to change the product list based on the selected type, if you want to change the product columns, please explain more detail about that, if the columns not fixed, you could consider dynamically generating the html content. "create button should create only that type of products" For this issue, when you create product, you could get the dropdownlist selected value and send it with the new product, and store it.

Comment: Besides, they seem to be two different questions, I suggest you could create a new separate thread for them and explain more details about the problem.